# How to require code from current workspace?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Say there is a file in a currently open workspace like `script.js` that exports a function:

```js
module.exports = function (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Running in an vscode extension context using typescript, is it possible to `require` that file and run the exported function inside?

Something like this:

```
const fun = require('/absolute/path/to/script.js')

console.log(fun(2, 2))
```

When i try to run the code above the `require` function returns `null`. While properly returning the required function if executed inside the node shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(module).exports = function(){}` instead in order to return your function directly.